# Не могу подружить MS Visual Studio 2015 и QT 5.12.2

Tags: qt5, visual-studio-2015

Дано: 
Установлена `MS Visul Studio 2015`

Требуется:
Установить в нее плагин, чтобы можно было разрабатывать приложения на `с++` в `QT 5.12`

Что сделано:

Официальный сайт `Qt.io` для установки `QT` предложил скачать `MaintEnance_Tool`, зарегистрироваться и, с его помощью, установить нужное расширение, что и было сделано. В списке доступных загрузочных самая свежей версией оказалась `QT 5.12 msvc2015_64`, которая и была выбрана для установки (Я читал про версию 5.6, но она не была предложена).

После установки, в `MS Visual Studio` появилась закладка `QT VS Toools`, из которой успешно запускаются все средства разработки, а в "визарде" новых проектов в разделе `С++` появился список заготовок для проектов в `QT`.

Далее в переменных окружения для переменной `Path` был добавлен маршрут `C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2015_64\bin;`, была добавлена переменная `QTDIR=C:\Qt\5.12.2\msvc2015_64\`.

После этого в "визарде" проектов был создан тестовый проект "консольное приложение QT", в свойствах проекта в закладке VC Directories были добавлены пути к хедерам и либам (без этого студия не видела `#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>`), и программа была запущена на компиляцию, что привело к удручающему результату:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, что с этим делать. Гугл ничем не помог.

На всякий случай фрагмент файла `qt_vars.targets`, на который она ругается

```
<!--// Read variables from Makefile -->
    <GetVarsFromMakefile
      Makefile="$(QtVarsWorkDir)\Makefile" VarDefs="@(QtVarDef)" ExcludeValues="$(QtVarsWorkDir)">
      <Output TaskParameter="OutVars" ItemName="QtVar"/>
    </GetVarsFromMakefile>
```

Как это исправить и заставить MS Visual Studio 2015 работать с QT?

P.S.: Используя это руководство https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfEttsC1vEA , я еще раз все переустановил (кроме Visual Studio) и поставил на этот раз QT 5.6, действуя по пунктам, как там рассказывается. Ничего не изменилось. Проект отказывается компилироваться с теми же сообщениями один в один.

Comment: смотрю в сообщения об ошибках и выглядит как будто используется c++/cli, а не чистый с++.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, я делал все по умолчанию, где устанавливается "чистый с++"? У меня все заточено под C#.

Comment: запускать инсталлятор студии и там искать.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @KoVadim похоже, что Вы правы - сейчас попробую переконфигурировать студию - в условиях  удаленки и самоизоляции в глуши это еще та песня

Comment: @KoVadim огромное спасибо, repair для VisualStudio все исправил. C++ был изначально установлен, но в нем что-то было не так, потому что приложения с MFC до этого прекрасно компилировались и запускались. Пожалуйста, оформите свою очень полезную подсказку в виде ответа, что бы еще больше поднять Вашу репутацию :).

Comment: @KoVadim, коллега, извиняюсь за назойливость, но оформите Ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я добавил Вам баллов в репутацию и закрыл вопрос. "Нативный" С++ тихо сломаться мог не только у меня. Такая ситуация, когда все ставиться, но не работает  возможна и других :). Возможно, что этот решенный вопрос кому-то сэкономит время и нервы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В мире с++ существует особый диалект с++ - называется с++/cli - это попытка Майкрософта сделать с++ на базе .NET. К сожалению, многие люди их путают. Qt - это все таки пока ещё чистый с++ проект и работать с таким особым с++ он не может. Если посмотреть на скриншот, то там там можно увидеть IEnumerate, .cs, что и подсказывает, что дело здесь не чисто.

Лечится тем, что нужно в инстлаляторе студии выбрать "с++ разработка и внимательно следить, что бы это была Native c++, а не Managed c++.